# Tkinter new windows won't close properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want my GUI to have a 'new window' option that will be just the same as the first one.

The problem is that it also has an exit(quit) button that won't work as it should - whenever I open the new window and then press the button, in the first click nothing happens and in the second one it closes both windows (if 3 windows are open so it'll close everything in the third click and so on).

This the relevant code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("250x150")
        self.app = Frame(self.root)
        self.app.grid()
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        sub_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=sub_menu)
        sub_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.__init__)
        sub_menu.add_command(label="Run", command=self.enter)
        sub_menu.add_separator()
        sub_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.app.quit)
```

I also tried to change:

```
sub_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.__init__)
```

to:

```
sub_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new window)
```

Where:

```
def new_window(self):
    class App(Application):
        Application.__init__(self)
```

Both do the same thing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Tkinter-Application there may only be one Tk-object. If the object is destroyed or destroyed by the garbage collector, Tkinter will be disabled. Use Toplevel for other other windows instead.

Try this instead:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *


class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = master
        self.root.geometry("250x150")
        self.app = Frame(self.root)
        self.app.grid()
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        sub_menu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=sub_menu)
        sub_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new)
        sub_menu.add_command(label="Run", command=self.enter)
        sub_menu.add_separator()
        sub_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)

    def new(self):
        window = Toplevel(tk)
        return Application(window)

    def quit(self):
        tk.destroy()

tk = Tk()
Application(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"If the object is dereferenced Tkinter will be disabled"_ - that is not an entirely true statement. You can dereference it, you just can't destroy it or let the garbage collector destroy it.  If the `Tk` instance lives in the global scope, it can be dereferenced without it being destroyed.